# How do I show open, closed, etc. on this topology?

Tags: general-topology, integers

Let $ \tau =  \{(-\infty,a)\ :\ a\in\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\} $ be a topology for $ \mathbb{R} $.

1. Is $[0,20]$ closed? Prove your answer.
2. Is $[0,20]$ open? Prove your answer.
3. Take $ A = \mathbb{Z} $. find $A^0,A^a,\overline{A}.$.

$ A^0 $ is the interior, $ A^a $ are the acucumulation points.

So, I believe that $ [0,20] $ is neither open nor closed because essentially it does not fit the form $ (-\infty,a) $ and the complement does not belong to the topology either. Is that sensical?

Also, what about $ \mathbb{Z} $? My guess is that it is closed because the complement of $ \mathbb{Z} $ is the infinite union of $ (a,b) $. But at the same time, I feel like it is neither open nor closed. A little lost... :(

Comment: You are right about [0,20].  You are wrong about Z because you are thinking the regular topology and not this topolog for which (a,b) is not open or closed.  As your feeling is correct, prove it.  This space is hyperconnected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only open sets (save for the empty set and all of $\mathbb{R}$ in this topology are intervals extending indefinitely to the left. Since $\mathbb{R}- [0,20]$ is not one of these it is not closed. Clearly, it is not open.  The interval $[0,20]$ contains no open sets so its interior must be void.  You should be able to deal similarly with the rest of the cases.